# How do we access the property of the object without calling object.property?

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to programming in general so this may be a very basic question.

*Also English isn't my native language, my appologies if I don't express myself very well.*

```
const questions = [{
      question: "what is 2 + 2 ?",
      answer: [{
        text: "4",
        correct: true
      }];
    ]

function showQuestion(question) {
  questionElement.innerText = question.question
}
```

I'm having trouble understanding, how do we access the question property of the object questions ("what is 2 + 2 ?") without calling its `object.property(questions.question)` but instead use `parameter.property(question.question)`?

Comment: You're missing a `}` in the object.

Comment: You are trying to access an object in array. You should try questions[0].question

Answer (score 1):

```js
const questions = [{
      question: "what is 2 + 2 ?",
      answer: [{
        text: "4",
        correct: true
      }]
      },
      {
      question: "what is 8 + 2 ?",
      answer: [{
        text: "10",
        correct: true
      }]
      },
       {
      question: "what is 8 - 4 ?",
      answer: [{
        text: "4",
        correct: true
      }]
      }
    ]


function showQuestion(id) {
 // questionElement.innerText = question.question
 console.log('question:'+ questions[id].question)
}

var id = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length)

showQuestion(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

`questions` is an array, presumably containing multiple objects like the one you showed.
You call the function like this:

```
var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length); // Get random array index
showQuestion(questions[i]);
```

When you do this, the selected array element becomes the value of `question` in the function. You can then access its properties with `question.propertyname`.

If you still don't understand, you need to review your learning material, the section that explains function calling.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach you you could use is a mixture of object destructuring and array destructuring to access object and array properties without explicitly specifying an index or using `obj.prop`. For example:

```js
const questions = [{
  question: "what is 2 + 2 ?",
  answer: [{
    text: "4",
    correct: true
  }]
}];

const [{
  question,
  answer
}] = questions;

const [{
  text,
  correct
}] = answer;

console.log(`${question}: ${text}`);
```